# Запятая в сложном (?) предложении

Tags: пунктуация, сложное-предложение

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, правильно ли расставлены запятые в данном предложении

*Майкл видел только буквы, и ничего, кроме них.*

и является ли это предложение сложным?  Спасибо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Майкл видел только буквы, и ничего, кроме них.**

Такой вариант встречается **чаще**, и он более **логичен**. Союз И в этом случае  ― **присоединительный.**

Если считать И соединительным союзом, то что означает сочетание ***буквы и ничего***?

Примеры

Их интересует только быстрая **прибыль, и ничего, кроме прибыли.** [С. Птичкин. Оборонный заказ (2003) // «Российская газета», 2003.05.15]

Только **солнце, и ничего, кроме солнца…** Ну, еще музыка, конечно! [А. Е. Рекемчук. Мамонты (2006)]

― А дело в том, что есть **только родство, и ничего кроме.** [Захар Прилепин. Санькя (2006)]

Запятая обычно отсутствует у устойчивом сочетании:

Так что говорите **правду и ничего кроме правды**! [Михаил Шишкин. Венерин волос (2004) // «Знамя», 2005]

Answer (score 1):

*Майкл видел только буквы и ничего, кроме них.*

Предложение простое. Основа - *Майкл видел*.